# how can i use nodejs to add a security group to an EC2 instance that is already running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

the title says almost everything, but just to make it clear, I DON'T want to

(1) use the console, OR
(2) use the CLI,

I want to add a SG dynamically using nodejs. I am shocked that there is not an obvious answer to this in the AWS documentation, but, if there is, I certainly can't find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this through [modifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) which takes `Groups` parameter:

> Changes the security groups for the network interface. The new set of groups you specify replaces the current set. You must specify at least one group, even if it's just the default security group in the VPC. You must specify the ID of the security group, not the name.

So you have to get `NetworkInterfaceId` of your instance (an instance can have multiple interfaces) first. You can do that using [describeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property). Once you have the `NetworkInterfaceId` you modify their SGs using `modifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute`.